# QSoundEffect does not reload source

Tags: qt

In my program it is possible to select a sound for an action. the sound is changeable, which means the `.wav` file gets replaced by another file.

This may cause the problem. When i replace the file and set the source of the `QSoundEffect` the sound does not change.

At the moment i am having a source like this:

```
//variable in .h
QUrl sound = "file:///"+soundDirectory+"sound.wav";
QUrl newSound = "file:///"+soundDirectory+"newSound.wav"; ;
QSoundEffect soundeffect;

//called in setSound() in .cpp
soundEffect.setSource(sound);
```

the sound loads without problem and i can play that sound.

i can change that sound with this code

```
// changing the sound in changeSound()
soundEffect.setSource(newSound);
```

this also works fine. the new sound is loaded and i can play it.

But it is also possible to change the sound files in the directory:

```
//changeSoundFile() 
QFile::remove(sound.toLocalFile());
QFile::copy(anyPossibleSound.toLocalFile(), sound.toLocalFile());
```

This also works and replaces the sound file in its directory with another.

If I call `setSound()` after changing the file. It seems like the file does not get reload. and the sound is not changed. This is also the problem if changed the sound in between (call `setSound` on startup, then changeSound, then changeSoundFile and the `setSound` again)

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the official docs, but you can find the implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-mobility/blob/master/src/multimedia/effects/qsoundeffect.cpp):

```
void QSoundEffect::setSource(const QUrl &url) {
    if (d->source() == url)
        return;

    d->setSource(url);

    emit sourceChanged();
}
```

The file does not get reloaded because the URL is the same. The implementation holds an internal cache with the data that has been loaded before, so when you play the file, nothing change.

The API does not provide a way of forcing the reset of the data source. You have two alternatives:

- Re-creating the `QSoundEffect` instance each time you modify the file.
- Changing the file name:

```
// Create a temporal file
const auto uuid = QUuid::createUuid();
const auto new_filename = uuid.toString() + ".wav";

// Copy the file
QFile::remove(sound.toLocalFile());
QFile::copy(anyPossibleSound.toLocalFile(), new_filename);
sound = QUrl(new_filename);

// Use it
soundEffect.setSource(sound);
```